# SL4 -> MEF DeploymentCatalog fails to download file with SecurityException

Tags: silverlight, mef, azure-blob-storage

I have a silverlight app which is hosted on an azure webrole.
I use the MEF deployment catalogs to load additional xap files at runtime.
Now I want to store these additional xap files in azure blob storage instead of the ClientBin folder.
I have placed these xap files in a public blob container.

However in my DownloadCompleted handler I get a SecurityException:

{System.Security.SecurityException ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Would this be related to cross domain calls? I have no idea what the problem could be.
If the xap files are loaded from the ClientBin folder it works just fine.
Maybe a cross domain issue?

Thank you!

My code is pretty straightforward:

var container = new AggregateCatalog();
    // grab social network provider
    foreach(string module in RequieredModules) // absolute uri's to the xap files in blob storage
    {
        container.Catalogs.Add(CreateCatalog(module));
    }
    CompositionHost.Initialize(container);

private DeploymentCatalog CreateCatalog(string uri)
{
    var catalog = new DeploymentCatalog(new Uri(uri));
    catalog.DownloadCompleted += new EventHandler

Comment: I found the solution.
I added a ClientAccessPolicy.xml to the root blob container and it worked!!!

Comment: These problems are traced immediately with Fiddler and other network tracing tools! Thank you for providing the answer, also!